# Change background and font color with angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Ok. So here is a noob question. I just started fooling around with angularjs and I was wondering if there is some sort of toggle function similar to ng-click or I have to build my own. What I want is to change the background and the font color of the body of my page, when the user checks the dark theme option.
 
I managed to change the color on the click function but I need it to come back to initial state when it is not checked. Any suggestions are welcome:)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-style="myStyle">
<label><input type="checkbox" ng-click="myStyle={background:'black', color:'white'}">Dark theme</label>
<script>
app = angular.module('myApp', []);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ng-class to apply new classes to elements. The docs are here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

I've done something similar in an app of my own, where selecting a theme from the options page applies a new class to the main content section of each page. I don't have the code available right now but I can post it in later if you would like.

Comment: Ya, thanks, I managed to figure it out. I will post an answer with the updated solution, maybe another poor soul will need this.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to add the style to the components .scss file or app.scss

`.darkTheme {background:'black', color:'white'}`

And then you could apply your style using the ng-class directive as Steve mentioned

`<body ng-app="myApp" ng-class="{'darkTheme' : darkToggle}">`

And add a model to the input

`<input type="checkbox" ng-model="darkToggle">`

Answer (score 0):

Working solution

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<style>
.dark-theme {
    color: white;
    background: black;
}
</style>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-class="{'dark-theme': dark}">
<label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="dark">Dark theme</label>
<script>
app = angular.module('myApp', []);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```